# Grouped products doesn't display on category page only at first time

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products, block-cache, category-listing

I am facing this unusual issue where **grouped products** are not being displayed only when the page loads for the **first time**.

After refreshing the category page all products are being displayed.

I have tried following 2 fix:

1. Disable and then Re-Enable:

> I have tried to ***disable-enable*** them, it fixed the issue
>   temporarily. But after 2 days it is again the same.

2. As mentioned in answer by Mudit, every time I save/update any product, the cache for **Blocks HTML output** gets *invalidated*:

> I have also tried a corn job with following code to clear invalidated
>   caches every minute:
>
> ```
> $invalid = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getInvalidatedTypes();
> foreach($invalid as $i)
> {
>     Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($i["id"]);
> }
> ```
>
> This refreshes the cache every minute but, issue still persists.

Any guidance on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now Fixed.

It was this extension **product filter** that we are using for filtration of attributes on category listing.

This extension was customized to not to take **Grouped products** into consideration for category listing. But, it worked on page refresh.

*(As we deleted the cache directory from cPanel, the grouped products were again not being displayed on first load after deleting cache)*

So, after page refresh listing was coming from cache.

Now we just rolled it back to its default functionality and this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your product caches and indexes are not invalidated before opening the category url

Comment: I have updated my question as per your answer.